# vue-cli how to build a lib from component and import it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli for build my lib with this command: 
`"build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib ./src/component.vue",`

How can i import my component from `dist` folder after build?

I'm tried

```
 // undefined
 import { component } from '../../myLib/dist/myLib.umd.js' 
 // undefined
 import myComponent'../../myLib/dist/myLib.umd.js' 
 // see picture below
 import * as myComponent'../../myLib/dist/myLib.umd.js'
```

Last variant gives me this:

[image]

My component.vue is valid(too large to show)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I pasted the dist directory under `node_modules/myLib` and then used my package with `import MyComponent from 'myLib'`

(alternatively if npm complains about not finding your lib you can publish it on npm, if it is not an issue to have it as public package).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. You have a little misunderstood, I have a handy tool for developing local packages: yalc(while I did not use it since my code does not work, what I wrote about at the top). but the fact is that I can not import my component if I import from a `dist/myLib.umd.js` If I import from `./src/component.vue`, everything is fine!

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe it's stupid but are you sure that your relative path is correct? (It should be if the last import is valid) anyway you may consider using aliases as explained [here](https://www.javascriptjanuary.com/blog/painless-paths-with-webpack-and-vsc) hope this helps!

Comment: I created another question here and it looks like `vue-cli-service` does not work correctly